# Assign date value to string (boost c++ libraries, posix time)

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I know how to output current date by using boost posix_time library:

```
   time_facet *format = new time_facet("%Y-%m-%d");
   cout.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), format));
   cout << second_clock::local_time() << endl;
```

But I don't know how to assign it to a string. I would like to ask you if you know how to do it and also to ask you, what does this line mean cout.imbue?

Comment: [*imbue*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imbue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a string stream.

```
std::ostringstream oss;

time_facet *format = new time_facet("%Y-%m-%d");
oss.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), format));
oss << second_clock::local_time();

std::string datetext = oss.str();
```

Consider keeping the imbued stream around for efficiency. Use

```
oss.clear();
oss.str("");
```

to reuse it.